# Issue passing arguements to constructor in different public class

Tags: java, variables, methods, constructor, double

I am having difficulty passing the `hours` and `hourlyWage` arguments to the constructor in the `Paycheck` class. The issue is as follows:

> ```
> symbol: variable hours
> location : class Paycheck
> ```

It repeats for every instances of hours or hourly wage in public class Paycheck.

The code is as follows

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PayDayCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hourly wage: ");
        double hourlyWage = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Hours worked: ");
        double hours = in.nextDouble();

        Paycheck paycheck = new Paycheck(hourlyWage, hours);
        System.out.println("Pay: " + paycheck.getPay());
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Paycheck {
    private double pay = 0;
    private double overtime = 0;
    private double overtimePay = 0;

    /*double hours;
    double hourlyWage; */
    Paycheck(double hourlyWage, double hours) {
        setPay(0);
    }

    public void setPay(double newPay) {
        if (hours > 40) {
            overtime = hours % 40;
            hours = hours - overtime;
        }
        overtimePay = hourlyWage * 1.5;
        pay = (hours * pay) + (overtime * overtimePay);
    }

    public double getPay() {
        return pay;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: what kind of difficulty? It'd be helpful if you posted the error and/or stack trace.

Comment: Why `setPay(0);`? your pay will always be zero no?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I posted above. When I try to compile I get an error that states for every reference of hours or hourlyWage in the public class Paycheck it states

error 37: cannot find symbol symbol
symbol : variable hours
location: class Paycheck

Comment: Changing the setPay(0); does not change the issues with finding the symbol

Comment: It is because you are not calling the setPay() method from the outside!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setPay` method is referring to `hours` and `hourlyWage`, which are parameters passed in to the constructor, making them local only to the constructor. They are not available to all methods in the class.  Those need to be uncommented at the class level if you want all methods to have access to them.

```
double hours;
double hourlyWage;

Paycheck(double hourlyWage, double hours) {
    this.hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    this.hours = hours;
    setPay(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have commented out member variable `hours`:

```
/*double hours;
double hourlyWage; */
```

but still try to refer to it, e.g.:

```
if (hours > 40) {
    overtime = hours%40;
    hours = hours - overtime;
}
```

If you need this variable - uncomment it.

Answer (score 0):

`hours` and `hourlyWage` are not defined!

Uncomment this part -

```
/*double hours;
double hourlyWage; */
```